# How to get count of all choices (say, from a survey) as columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, survey

Let me start by saying that I am beginner in pandas.
I have a problem wherein my initial dataframe looks like below.
For each question, we got either of 3 answers recorded (Yes, No or Why).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Qn1' : ['Yes', 'No', 'Why', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
               'Qn2' : ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Why', 'Why', 'Yes'],
               'Qn3' : ['Why', 'Why', 'Why', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
               'Qn4' : ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Why'],
              })
```

How can we get a dataframe with counts of each answers against the questions. Eg: a df that looks similar to below one

```
.   Yes  No  Why
Qn1  5   2   1
Qn2  1   3   6
Qn3  0   4   2
Qn4  4   2   1
```

groupby() works on columns, but couldn't get it work right for rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`apply`** with **`pd.value_counts`**:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T

     No  Why  Yes
Qn1   3    1    2
Qn2   2    2    2
Qn3   1    3    2
Qn4   3    1    2
```

If you have missing values, this will fill with `NaN`, so you so you way want to **`fillna`** if that is a possibility:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Qn1': ['Yes'], 'Qn2': ['No'], 'Qn3': ['Why']})
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T

      No  Why  Yes
Qn1  NaN  NaN  1.0
Qn2  1.0  NaN  NaN
Qn3  NaN  1.0  NaN

# With fillna()
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0).astype(int)

     No  Why  Yes
Qn1   0    0    1
Qn2   1    0    0
Qn3   0    1    0
```

If not all of the items are in *any* column, you may want to define a `CategoricalDtype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Qn1': ['Yes'], 'Qn2': ['No'], 'Qn3': ['No']})
df.apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0).astype(int)

# Missing 'why'
     No  Yes
Qn1   0    1
Qn2   1    0
Qn3   1    0
```

But using a `CategoricalDtype`:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

ct_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=['Yes', 'No', 'Why'], ordered=False)

df.astype(ct_type).apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0).astype(int)

     No  Why  Yes
Qn1   0    0    1
Qn2   1    0    0
Qn3   1    0    0
```

Comment: I am getting a different result when doing the first command. Its not showing the Qn label on the left. Also, values are in floats.  `    No Why Yes
    0 2.0 1.0 1.0
    1 3.0 1.0 NaN
    2 1.0 2.0 1.0
    3 1.0 1.0 2.0
    4 NaN 1.0 3.0
    5 2.0 1.0 1.0`

Comment: Thanks @user3483203. df.apply(pd.value_counts).T worked on initial dataframe. I was using it on tranposed dataframe and got wrong result. Thanks again.